# Low-side LED switch BJT not switching

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, led, bjt

[image]

I have a simple low-side switching circuit. LED_DS signal is a 5 V microcontroller GPIO signal, driving the base of my NPN transistor, MMBT3904. This should drive the N-channel AO3400A MOSFET gate between a pulled-up 12 V and ~0 V when the BJT is off. An LED (LED_D) is connected in series with the drain of the MOSFET. The LED is always powered by 12 V, so the AO3400A should switch its negative-side between ~0 V and hi-Z.

I've quadruple-checked the datasheets, pinouts and everything. I've built the circuit on breadboard with 2N3904 and 2N7000 BJTs and found it to work as expected.

I've then taken delivery of the PCB assembly with this circuit from my supplier. This uses C20526 and C20917 for the BJTs. Here, the BJT will remain stuck on, with its collector always reading ~11.5 V regardless of the level on LED_DS.

This behaviour is replicated across all of these boards from the supplier.

I can only think of 3 possible explanations.

1. The supplier has mad a mistake on the datasheet references vs. the actual parts placed and their pinouts
2. There's some active component stuff that I just don't seem to understand
3. I'm being misled

Does anyone have a clue what might be happening?

Comment: "BJT always on" and "collector at 11.5V" don't really seem to line up.  Have you measured the voltage at the base of the BJT?  And the actual resistances of R8 and R10?

Comment: Use the diode test of a good multimeter to see if the diode drops of the NPN as are expected. If other components on the board may interfere with this, cut traces and/or remove the BJT to test off-board.

Comment: Why the BJT? Why not drive the gate directly.

Comment: Vir, You're right, the 'always on' is a mistake. It's always off. The voltage at the base of the BJT is at ~5V. R8 @ 1k, R10 @ 10k.

ErikR, Thanks, will do.

Winny, The BJT allows the MOSFET to be driven by the 12V supply. This reduces R_on of the MOSFET.

Comment: You mention two BJTs for the finished part but your schematic only shows one???

Comment: Are you switching the GPIO between high and low voltage, or high and low impedance?

Comment: If the BJT emitter is grounded, its base can't be at 5 V.  I suspect that the pinout of the BJT is different than your board expects.

Comment: What markings are on the parts that are populated? Photos preferable.

Comment: What are "C20526" and "C20917"?